# jQuery validate - pushing an error to a field

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a form with a huge number of fields to be validated; and I use the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for that purpose. There are, however, a few fields that need AJAX validation, and I was forced to not use `remote`, because the server can return a variety of responses (as JSON) for those fields (as I understand, for `remote`, the server can only send back a boolean response). Currently, I am manually writing the server's validation response to the DOM.

I would like to programmatically push the error message (after having parsed it from the server response) to the field via `$.validator`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"as I understand, for remote, the server can only send back a boolean response"*

[You are mistaken about that.  Simply refer to the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).  The response can be a boolean value, `undefined`, `null`, or a string.  If the server returns a string, the string is used as the error message.

> **The response is evaluated as
>   JSON** and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`,
>   `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; **or
>   a string**, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to
>   display as the error message.

The solution is to have your server code return `true` when you want to field to be "valid" and return the error message as a JSON string when you want that field to be "invalid".  The plugin will place the error message on the page automatically.